# Insert if names do not exist and return ids if exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, upsert

Suppose I have an array of string "a","b","c","d","e".

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id   int   GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name text  UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('a'), ('d');  -- assigned IDs 1 and 2
```

What will be the query to pass an array of strings and insert each if that `name` doesn't exist and return all IDs for the given array? In this example, it should return `1,2,3,4,5` as an output of SQL execution.

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: Hardik, in good faith I've tried to create what you I could parse in SQL. Please complete your example and show your desired results.

Comment: And I added a `UNIQUE` constraint to the setup. Would make a lot of sense for your given question. Please fix if we are guessing wrong. The point is: Your question ***needs*** an exact table definition and some more info to be unambiguous.

Comment: Is concurrent write access to the same table possible? If so, can you afford to lose IDs in very rare cases? And do you need to know which row was inserted and which was selected (already existed)? Do you need an *array* or a *set* in return? And is the order of returned IDs relevant? Same as input array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the recurring problem of ***`INSERT` or `SELECT`***, related to the common UPSERT, but not the same. `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO ...` (commonly called UPSERT), introduced with Postgres 9.5, is instrumental in any case.

Assuming the simple case **without concurrent write load** on the table:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo (
>   id   int   GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
>   name text  UNIQUE
> );
> INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('a'), ('d');  -- assigned IDs 1 and 2
> ```

> ```
> WITH input(name) AS (SELECT unnest('{a,b,c,d,e}'::text[]))  -- input array once
> , ins AS (
>    INSERT INTO foo(name) 
>    TABLE  input
>    ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
>    RETURNING id
>    )
> SELECT f.id
> FROM   input i
> JOIN   foo   f USING (name)
> UNION  ALL
> TABLE  ins;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  4 |
> |  5 |
> |  7 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fe63bb4aece40bf774af5bb9bd1801c9)*

Note the missing serial IDs `3` and `6`. A side effect of UPSERT is that conflicting rows burn a serial number since default values are fetched *before* checking for conflicts, and sequences are never set back. That should be irrelevant, since gaps in serial numbers are to be expected at all times. Meaning, you cannot rely on a result `1,2,3,4,5` for the given example (and assumed setup).

Detailed explanation and alternative solutions - especially for **concurrent write load**:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `INSERT` in a CTE `RETURNING id` and `SELECT` from that CTE and `UNION ALL` a `SELECT` fetching all the matching `id`s already in `foo`.

```
WITH cte
AS (
INSERT INTO foo
            (name)
            SELECT a_name
                   FROM unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) a_name
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM foo
                                     WHERE name = a_name)
            RETURNING id
)
SELECT id
       FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT id
       FROM foo
            INNER JOIN unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) a_name
                       ON name = a_name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b9c863/1)