# Why is the serial primary key incrementing despite a using "On Conflict Do Nothing?

Tags: postgresql, sequence, postgresql-13, upsert

I have the below table in PostgreSQL 13:

#### table name: newtable

```
field       type 
-----       ----    
Seq         bigserial   
code        varchar
```

`Seq` is the primary key (auto-increment)
`Code` is a unique key index

```
Insert Into newtable (Code) Values ('001') On Conflict(Code) Do Nothing   --> Seq value is 1
Insert Into newtable (Code) Values ('001') On Conflict(Code) Do Nothing
Insert Into newtable (Code) Values ('001') On Conflict(Code) Do Nothing

Insert Into newtable (Code) Values ('002') On Conflict(Code) Do Nothing   --> Seq value is 4
```

Why is Seq 4? Is there any way to increase value on successful inserts only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PostgreSQL 15 comes the MERGE command. Inserts made using this command don't burn sequence numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (
  seq INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  code varchar UNIQUE
);
```

Run the following statement a couple of times, then change value `001` to `002` and repeat. Value `002` gets the next available seq number assigned.

```
MERGE INTO newtable n
USING (SELECT '001' AS code) AS u
ON (n.code = u.code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
code = u.code
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (code)
VALUES ('001');         

SELECT * FROM newtable ORDER BY 1;

seq code
1   001
2   002
```

Comment: @Don2: Note that `MERGE` is not an equivalent replacement. I added some explanation to my answer to.

Answer (score 8):

#### Use `MERGE` instead?

`MERGE` (added with Postgres 15) looks similar on the surface, but is quite different under the hood. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html#id-1.9.3.156.8)

> When `MERGE` is run concurrently with other commands that modify the
> target table, the usual transaction isolation rules apply; see
> [Section 13.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) for an explanation on the behavior at each isolation
> level. You may also wish to consider using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` as
> an alternative statement which offers the ability to run an `UPDATE`
> if a concurrent `INSERT` occurs. There are a variety of differences
> and restrictions between the two statement types and they are not
> interchangeable.

In particular, `MERGE` cannot reliably suppress unique violations under concurrent write load, like `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` can (the command in question). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED)

> If `MERGE` attempts an `INSERT` and a unique index is present and a
> duplicate row is concurrently inserted, then a uniqueness violation
> error is raised; `MERGE` does not attempt to avoid such errors by
> restarting evaluation of `MATCHED` conditions.

A minor (and typically unimportant) side effect of the different approach is that `MERGE` does not normally burn serial numbers. (It still can, like when an exception is raised ...)

If you don't have concurrent write load, or if the discussed issues don't matter to you, then `MERGE` can be an alternative. (Then you probably didn't need `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` in the first place.) [Rudi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/133337/rudi-broekhuizen) added an answer with a code example.

#### Your questions about `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

> Why does the Seq value keep increasing?

The reason is that `DEFAULT` values (and triggers and anything else that might change row values) are applied *before* checking for duplicates (trying to enter index tuples). And `serial` numbers are designed to defend against race conditions under concurrent load. The underlying `SEQUENCE` does not "take back" numbers once it has been incremented. There are other scenarios that would burn serial numbers. So gaps in serial numbers are to be expected. As long as you don't burn numbers at a gigantic rate, this should not be a problem.

> Is there any way to only increase the Seq value if it is successfully inserted?

Not without (more or less) seriously compromising performance, like by using [`SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) or manual locking strategies. That's the reason why the `ON CONFLICT` clause ("UPSERT") exists in the first place.

**If** you don't actually have concurrent writes to the same table (are you sure?), this alternative query would avoid burning serial numbers:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (code)
SELECT '001'
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM newtable WHERE code = '001';
```

It's slightly more expensive in the non-conflicting case as it first checks for existence in the index and then actually enters the new row in table and index(es). But slightly faster for conflicting cases. There is a tiny window between checking and writing where race conditions can cause problems under concurrent write load. That's when we use an UPSERT.

Related:

- [Sequential increment skipping numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53643040/939860)
- [Insert if names do not exist and return ids if exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208586/insert-if-names-do-not-exist-and-return-ids-if-exist/208610#208610)
- [serial in Postgres is being increased even though I added on conflict do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37204749/939860)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)